# how to make an image lopsided?

Tags: css, clip-path

I came across a website in which there was an image that was lopsided, I was wondering how it's done. I tried to find out how it's done in Chrome Inspect tool but unfortunately I couldn't find out.

[image: here is a screenshot]

I guess one way of doing it would be to use a photo editor and add this white space to the bottom of the picture before adding it to the page but they have possibly used another method cause the original image doesn't have a white space under it.

Thanks.

***EDIT***: as it's stated in the answers, there are several great ways to do this. one is to rotate the picture, the other is to use Clip-Path.
I know the question wasn't so fundamental but I just asked it out of curiosity.
**Cheers**

Comment: What have you tried before? Without adding your code snippet we can't help you sorry.

Comment: `clip-path` is a hint.

Comment: @Viira [link](https://www.nabzino.com) here is the website I took the screenshot from.

Comment: You can use transform: skewX(25deg); with what degrees you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew

Comment: Try this clip-path tool https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @PIIANTOM Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div named `av-extra-border-inner` was rotated -5 degrees
And they've added the following

```
.av-extra-border-inner
    {
     width:110%;
     position:absolute;
    }
```

to make it attached to the div

Un check the line I have commented out here and see the result.

You can find out more about clipping and masking here : https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

```css
.avia_transform .av-extra-border-element.border-extra-diagonal.border-extra-diagonal-inverse .av-extra-border-inner {
    /* -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); */
    /*transform: rotate(-5deg);*/
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    transform-origin: left top;
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this. `clip-path` is one option; `transform: rotate(Ndeg)`is another. Yet another way of doing this is using `skew`;

```html
    <div class="skewed">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
.skewed {
  height: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewY(-10deg) translateY(-50%);
}
.skewed .image {
  height:150%;
  background-size: 100%;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  background-image: url(your/image.jpg);
}
```